# Make textfile all one line without a return to a new line c++

Tags: c++

I have the following textfile (essai.txt):

```
i am a second year student
my account number is 1039
19 1 2019
```

My desired output:

```
i am a second year student my account number is 1039 19 1 2019
```

I am not figuring out how to read the new line return, i have tried getline,tried to read a blank space but obviously it doesn't work..
My code:

```
char line[50];
ifstream o("essai.txt");
ofstream s("essai.txt");

while (o >> line) {
    //Here i am not figuring it out 
}
```

Comment: Simple: `while (std::getline(o,line)) {
   s << line << ' ';

}` Also better declare `line` as `std::string line;` rather than a raw `char` array. If you want to avoid the trailing blank, there are techniques you can use, just distinguishing the first iteration from the following ones and put the blank in front of the output.

Comment: Doesn't `ofstream s("essai.txt");` overwrite the text file?

Comment: @melpomene Good point.

Comment: You can't write to the file at the same time as you're reading from it (at least it's not advisable to do it that way). Read into a string first, then write only once you've finished all the reading. Or just use two different file names.

Comment: it worked having two files one to read from and the other to write on but can't i do it on the same one?

Comment: Better to finish the read, then finish the write, then do rename/replace in the filesystem.

Comment: @Kenny You can do it with a single `std::fstream` as shown in my answer, no need for rename/replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you possibly could do successfully:

```
std::string line;
std::string single_line;
fstream x("essai.txt");
first_iteration = true;
// Read all the data from the file and accumulate the results into a single line
while (std::getline(x,line)) {
    if(first_iteration) { 
       first_iteration = false;
    }
    else {
        single_line += ' ';
    }
    single_line += line;
}
// Position the file write pointer back to the beginning ...
// (that's most probably not needed at all, since the writing position was
// never changed in the previous code)
x.seekp(std::ios_base:beg);
// ... and write out the formerly accumulated input.
x << single_line;
```

Comment: The `first_iteration` variable could be removed and the loop be simplified like this: `if (std::getline( x, single_line )) { while (std::getline( x, line )) { single_line += ' '; single_line += line; }}`